# Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM] require() of ES Module is not supported

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite, remix.run

I developed a [Shopify Remix App](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-app-template-remix) prior to the template's migration to Vite. There is a library [@shopify/polaris-viz](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@shopify/polaris-viz) I am using for charts. However it was consistently throwing the error `ERR_REQUIRE_ESM string-width` while attempting to run the project. It was subsequently fixed by using `serverDependenciesToBundle` as suggested [here](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-app-template-remix/issues/334). However now, I'm having trouble migrating this to vite implementation. Since there is no `remix.config.ts` anymore what should be the best way to handle the following error?

```
require() of ES Module /app/node_modules/d3-scale/src/index.js from /app/node_modules/@shopify/polaris-viz-core/build/cjs/utilities/createGradient.js not supported.
Instead change the require of index.js in /app/node_modules/@shopify/polaris-viz-core/build/cjs/utilities/createGradient.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
```

Looking at the discussions [7872](https://github.com/remix-run/remix/discussions/7872) and [7865](https://github.com/remix-run/remix/issues/7865) on the official remix repo doesn't seem to be working. As suggested in [7865](https://github.com/remix-run/remix/issues/7865#issuecomment-1789900955) I put the erroneous package, in this case `d3-scale` to ssr -> noExternal but this doesn't seem to be working.

```
ssr: {
    noExternal: ["d3-scale"]
}
```

Steps to reproduce the problem:

1. Setup a new project
2. Add @shopify/polaris-viz to the project
3. import { PolarisVizProvider } from "@shopify/polaris-viz";

Any help with this is highly appreciated.